# Не получается внести данные в БД из массива

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

Всем привет! Моя задача - вывести данные из подмассивов одного большого массива в БД. Подмассивы выглядят вот так:

```
0 => array (size=8)
'ID' => int 1
'Name' => string 'A_fortiori' (length=13)
'Address' => string 'ВырСредства_культРечи_2007_148' (length=50)
'Equal_elements' => string 'отсутствуют' (length=22)
'Homonymy_count' => int 0
'Polysemy_count' => int 0
'Is_inverted' => int 0
'Is_pluralis' => int 0
```

Я создал в БД таблицу со следующими столбцами:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID             | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Term           | varchar(1000) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Address        | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Equal_elements | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Homonymy_count | int(10)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Polysemy_count | int(10)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Is_inverted    | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Is_pluralis    | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Путем отладки через var_dump я убедился, что запросы доходят до бд и вручную можно без проблем записать хотя бы одну строку данных из массива.

Обрадовавшись я пошел повторять успешный запрос в БД в цикле с использованием implode:

```
foreach ($dataDb as $term) 
    {
    $forImp = "', '";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO terms2(ID, Term, Address, Equal_elements, Homonymy_count, Polysemy_count, Is_inverted, Is_pluralis) VALUES (implode($forImp, $term))";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    }
```

Но в цикле данные не захотели записываться в БД.

При выполнении цикла в дампе sql появляется ошибка

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Причем появляется и если  перечислить все столбцы в таблице БД, и если этого не делать. Колдунства с экранированием кавычек в разделителе implode тоже не помогли.

Понимаю, что данная ошибка сигнализирует о несоответствии числа столбцов и количества вводимых данных, но ведь и тех, и тех 8 штук. var_dump строки, которая идет в VALUES, выглядит так:

```
'51', 'АББРЕВИАТУРА', 'СЛТ_общ_2007_27', 'сложносокращенное_слово_|_инициальный_тип_сложносокращенных_слов_|_акроним', '0', '2', '0', '0' (length=217)
```

Видимо дело в каких-то нюансах sql или я что-то еще упустил? Спасибо за любой совет.

**UPD**
Попробовал пошаманить с переменной $sql - вытащил функцию из SQL-запроса в отдельную переменную:

```
$forImp = "', '";
    $example = implode($forImp, $term);
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO terms2(ID, Term, Address, Equal_elements, Homonymy_count, Polysemy_count, Is_inverted, Is_pluralis) VALUES ($example)";
```

Ошибка поменялась:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '', 'Аббревиатура', 'ЭнцСлСпр_общ_2008_500', 'отсутс' at line 1'

Судя по тексту ошибки, она возникает на последнем подмассиве -  (непонятно, почему тогда line 1). Пробовал менять местами массивы - ошибка срабатывает именно на последнем...

Еще один момент - у меня много повторяющихся ячеек в столбце term - например, девять строк может повторяться слово "аббревиатура". Может ли это повлиять на возникновение ошибки?

Comment: Проверьте значение переменной `$sql` и почините.

Comment: vp_arth спасибо за комментарий и наводку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел косяк.

В sql-запросе в VALUES я пытался скормить значения подмассива, сгруппированные функцией implode. Моя задумка была сделать примерно такую строку:

```
'1', '2', '3'
```

Однако эта функция НЕ вставляет разграничитель в начале и в конце результирующей строки, т.е. в VALUES по итогу уходило

```
1', '2', '3
```

Решил вопрос добавлением кавычек к результату функции implode:

```
foreach ($dataDb as $term) 
    {
    $forImp = "', '";
    $example = "'" . implode($forImp, $term) . "'";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO terms2 VALUES ($example)";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    var_dump($example);
    }
```

Comment: Не забудьте подумать о том, что будет, если внутри ваших данных встретится апостроф. Ну и вцелом про sql-инъекции стоит почитать.

Comment: vp_arth, спасибо!